# No such directory/files after joining 2 folderpath

Tags: python, pandas

```
fph= pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\anon\desk\inside') #filedirectory


fp1 = fph.joinpath(fph, '\inside\maps.xlsx') 

Nmap= pd.read_excel(fp1, sheet_name='Swis')
```

I want to join 2 folder path and able to read the maps.xlsx, but when run the code its say that `'There are no directory or files '\inside\maps.xlsx`

Comment: I think you want to do `fph.joinpath('inside", "maps.xlsx')`.

Answer (score 1):

It is trying to read: `r'C:\Users\anon\desk\inside\inside\maps.xlsx'`. I think you want: `r'C:\Users\anon\desk\inside\maps.xlsx'` so you need:

```
fp1 = fph.joinpath('maps.xlsx')
```

Comment: thanks mate, i was thinking what could be the problem, and base on your answer, i see why its keep saying there is no such as directiory when i use r'C:\Users\anon\desk\inside\inside\maps.xlsx